# XPages create a full text index in SSJS

Tags: xpages, full-text-indexing

I have a DB that must be full text indexed, so I added the code below to create one if it is not allready indexed:

```
if (database.isFTIndexed()){
    database.updateFTIndex(false)
} else {
    var options:int = database.FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS + database.FTINDEX_ATTACHED_FILES + database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE
    database.createFTIndex(options , true);
    database.updateFTIndex(false);
}
sessionScope.put("ssSelectedView","vwWFSProfile")
```

When it runs I get the following error:
Error source
Page Name:/xpWFSAdmin.xsp
Control Id: button2
Property: onclick

Exception
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
com.ibm.jscript.types.GeneratedWrapperObject$StaticField incompatible with com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSValue

Expression

1: #{javascript:if (database.isFTIndexed()){
   2:   database.updateFTIndex(false)
   3: } else {
   4:   var options:int = database.FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS + database.FTINDEX_ATTACHED_FILES + database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE
   5:   database.createFTIndex(options , true);
   6:   database.updateFTIndex(false);
   7: }
   8: sessionScope.put("ssSelectedView","vwWFSProfile")}

It is choking on line 4 it does not like the summing of the parameters. So I comment out line 4 and change line 5 to read database.createFTIndex(4, true)
 then I get this error:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=5, col=18: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.createFTIndex(number, boolean) null

JavaScript code

1: if (database.isFTIndexed()){
   2:   database.updateFTIndex(false)
   3: } else {
   4:   //var options:int = database.FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS + database.FTINDEX_ATTACHED_FILES + database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE
   5:   database.createFTIndex(4 , true);
   6:   database.updateFTIndex(false);
   7: }
   8: sessionScope.put("ssSelectedView","vwWFSProfile")

Can't seem to get it to work. I can go into the DB and manually create the index so it is not a rights issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can read from the help, you can not use database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE as parameter for createFTIndex() only for setFTIndexFrequency().

So remove the use of database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE and do this:

```
var options:int = database.FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS + database.FTINDEX_ATTACHED_FILES;
database.createFTIndex(options , true);
```

You can then call setFTIndexFrequency() like this:

```
database.setFTIndexFrequency(database.FTINDEX_IMMEDIATE);
```

Comment: Will try that. I had a single piece of code where I setFTIndexFrequency to Immediate didn't realize it could not be used in the  options. Now that I look at the Help I overlooked the issue of Immediate could not be called as an option. It is not really obvious, but it is there. Thanks

Comment: I have gone a bit further really confusing. I created a simple XPage with just a button and this code:<br> if (database.isFTIndexed()){
 database.updateFTIndex(false)
} else {
 database.createFTIndex(0 , false);
 database.setFTIndexFrequency(4);
 database.updateFTIndex(false);
}<br> If Irun this on the local replica copy it works fine. If I try to run it on the server copy I get a 500 error and the index is not created. tried using database.FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS and it fails all the time so just added the numbers. I have to step away from this for awhile, I'm so frustrated.